# Is there a solution to have self-signed certificate but still be publicly trusted in Nice DCV?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on integrating the [NICE DCV SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dcv/latest/websdkguide/what-is.html) with the server running on AWS EC2. But it uses a self-signed certificate by default for connecting to it. We do have the option to change it [like so](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dcv/latest/adminguide/manage-cert.html) but I think I would need to add the *.compute.amazonaws.com as SAN to the certificate.

And that is obviously owned by AWS.

So is there anyway to do this?
The AWS support team suggested using [load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/what-is-load-balancing.html?icmpid=docs_elbv2_console#elb-features) but that means I can't control which devices connects to which client.

I was thinking of implementing something like a proxy server, but am not sure if that is the right way to go about it.

Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is paying for a public cert an option? Could you elaborate why you would lose control which devices connects to which client if there is a load balancer in between?

Comment: @jingx I am ready to pay for a certificate, but will that allow me to add that domain as SAN? I would lose control because each client needs to connect to a particular server and that, if I understand correctly, won't happen with a load balancer, right? It would automatically direct the request to machine with the lowest load.

Comment: Not necessarily the lowest load, but you are correct that if you have multiple servers behind an NLB, a client doesn't get to select which one to go to. But then if you do have multiple servers, and your clients need to be able to connect selectively, that means each server needs its own cert because a client will connect to one of them by its specific DNS name.

Comment: Yeah. But to create a public certificate for that I would need to be able to access the DNS or admin email for compute.amazonaws.com which is the EC2 public dns domain, right?

Comment: If that is the case, you can request an elastic IP for each server, get your own domain, and host the domain on Route53, configure hostnames from the domain to point to the elastic IPs, and then get public certs for these hostnames (or a wildcard cert for the whole domain but that might be expensive depending on how many servers you have)

Comment: That might work! I will try it out and update it here soon!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234231/discussion-between-guidingfox-and-jingx).

Comment: @jingx I did something similar to what you said. I created a wildcard certificate for my domain, installed it on the DCV server, then used the cloudflare api to create an A record with a name and the elastic IP. It is working fine now. Thank you!